# How to check version of make on HP-UX

Tags: unix, makefile, hp-ux

I'm new to HP-UX system and having one problem with running a make file.

```
Make: Must be a separator on rules line 14.  Stop.
```

I suspect this is due to older version of make deployed on the machine (since the same make file works on other unix and linux based systems).
Questions:-

- How do I check the version of make (does HP-UX uses GNU make?) on HP-UX
- How to upgrade make to a newer version.

I tried getting information on make using `man make` but couldn't find anything on version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda brute force and might take a while, but you could try listing version info about all installed software using

```
$ swlist -a revision -a title
```

Then search its output for whatever package looks like it'd have `make` in it.

#### Reference

Man page for [`swlist`](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/unix/usail/man/hpux/swlist.1.html)

Comment: thanks. it did work. make 3.81. But not sure this is GNU make (This could be HP-UX own implementation), which is causing problems with make file written for GNU make.

Answer (score 0):

Most programs have a **--version** switch (all GNU core utilities have one).

Comment: doesn't work. make --version
Make: Unknown flag argument -.  Stop.

Comment: worked on CentOS (where my make file is also running fine).  make --version
GNU Make 3.81

Comment: At least you can be reasonably sure it's not GNU make. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Install gmake instead! Default make on hp ux does not works well with Makefiles written to be compatible with GNU make.